# Calling a function in Bash script

Tags: bash, function, shell, scripting, external

I have done enough searching to find this out, but with no luck.  I am trying to write a Bash script that has to call a function which is defined somewhere else.

For example, I have a shell test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Shell - test.sh

function1() {
   echo "Inside function 1"
}

function1
function2

exit 0
```

I have a different file which has function2,

```
$ cat function2

function2() {
   echo "Inside function 2"
}
```

Now, when I run test.sh, 
   (Q1) How does it know where to find function2 ?
   (Q2) It is not showing echo output from function 2

Any inputs would be greatful.

Hi, Thanks for your answers. But, what surprises me is that, when I execute the shell using "$./test.sh", I am getting an output of "Inside function 1". If the shell does not find "function2", it should throw an error that "function not found or something". I feel that somehow the function is called but the message is not shown.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: You `source` the second file in the first (you can use `.` as a shortcut for `source`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's the other way around, the `source` command is the long version of the `.` command, but the `.` came first.

Comment: I always get that backwards, thanks. I get the chicken or the egg wrong too `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comment, you `source` `file2` in `file1`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Shell - test.sh

function1() {
    echo "Inside function 1"
}

if [ -r "file2" ]  ## make sure file2 is readable by file1
then
   . "file2"       ## source file2 in file1.
                   ## Yes the . is a command! Check 'help .'
else               ## otherwise show error and exit
    printf "error: file2 not readable by file1.\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi

function1
function2

exit 0
```

Comment: Not sure who down-voted this. The answer is correct.

Comment: It's the new members of the juvenile downvote squad that came with the new fall semester.

Answer (score -1):

You have to import the other file that has function 2 with complete path, in the file that has function 1. That way you will have access to the functions of file 2.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answers. But, what surprises me is that, when I execute the shell  using "$./test.sh", I am getting an output of "Inside function 1". If the shell does not find "function2", it should throw an error that "function not found or something".  I feel that somehow the function is called but the message is not shown.